# mysql - count null filed of left joint table

Tags: mysql

```
Table Article id title
Table Comment id articleID comment

SELECT a.*, count(c.id) FROM Article as a LEFT JOINT Comment as c 
ON c.articleID = a.id
LIMIT 0, 10
```

I want to display article with number comments, but it only list 1 result (has comment).

and do not list the articles do not have comments.

How to list all articles (have comments/ have not comment) ?

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to ask. Questions end with the character `'?'`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you have to use `GROUP BY` in your base query

```
SELECT a.id, a.title, COUNT(c.id) comment_count
  FROM Article a LEFT JOIN Comment c 
    ON c.articleID = a.id
 GROUP BY a.id, a.title
```

Sample output:

```
| ID |  TITLE | COMMENT_COUNT |
-------------------------------
|  1 | Title1 |             2 |
|  2 | Title2 |             0 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ac67d/2)** demo

Now if you are using `LEFT JOIN` and want only articles with comments you need to apply `HAVING` clause

```
SELECT a.id, a.title, COUNT(c.id) comment_count
  FROM Article a LEFT JOIN Comment c 
    ON c.articleID = a.id
 GROUP BY a.id, a.title
HAVING comment_count > 0
```

or simply use `INNER JOIN` as Andy suggested because inner join will filter out all mismatches (meaning all articles that have no corresponding records in comments table and vice versa). *Using `INNER JOIN` in most cases is faster then using `LEFT JOIN`*.

```
SELECT a.id, a.title, COUNT(c.id) comment_count
  FROM Article a JOIN Comment c 
    ON c.articleID = a.id
 GROUP BY a.id, a.title
```

Both will produce:

```
| ID |  TITLE | COMMENT_COUNT |
-------------------------------
|  1 | Title1 |             2 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ac67d/5)** demo

Answer (score 0):

Do not LEFT JOIN...

When you left join, you simply join one matching row to table Article, you want to simply join the tables as you are then grouping by the article id and counting the grouped results

```
SELECT a.*, count(a.id) FROM Article as a, Comment as c 
WHERE c.articleID = a.id
GROUP BY a.id
LIMIT 0, 10
```

Comment: So what is your proposal?

Comment: The comments maybe yes or no